# iOS versus CSS font size - they are not equal

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I have an iOS application that adjusts font sizes based on a size set in the browser. The CSS font e.g. Arial 12pt does not equate well to equivalent sizes set in iOS. Smaller font sizes in CSS (below say 16pt) are rendered smaller in the app and larger font sizes (eg. above 100pt) are rendered larger (but ultimately smaller) in the iOS app.

Does anybody know the correct conversion of points between the two systems?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can show an example of how you implement this? I'd like to verify that you're using the `viewport` metatag to make sure the page doesn't scale on a mobile device.

Comment: I build the app from scratch based on downloaded vars from a shared server. I don't touch the viewport on the device itself - it's all native.

Comment: Ah okay, I though this was a browser based project. My bad

Comment: An alternative is to calculate a font size based on % of some fixed element, but it seems strange font sizes aren't standardised, right?